# Accessing non-consecutive elements of a list or string in python

Tags: python, string, list, indexing, slice

As far as I can tell, this is not officially not possible, but is there a "trick" to access arbitrary non-sequential elements of a list by slicing?

For example:

```
>>> L = range(0,101,10)
>>> L
[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

Now I want to be able to do

```
a,b = L[2,5]
```

so that `a == 20` and `b == 50`

One way besides two statements would be something silly like:

```
a,b = L[2:6:3][:2]
```

But that doesn't scale at all to irregular intervals.

Maybe with list comprehension using the indices I want?

```
[L[x] for x in [2,5]]
```

I would love to know what is recommended for this common problem.

Comment: `a,b = L[2],L[5]`?

Comment: @roippi - That does make it look simple, but I wanted to apply this directly to the output of a function that returns a list, without calling the function twice or re-assigning that to a variable and then grabbing.

Comment: I'm inclined to say that your list comprehension is the best you can do. Or, if you don't need an actual list, use a generator expression, like in Shashank Gupta's answer (though if you only need it once, you could just put the genexp inline, rather than making a function to return it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this?

```
def select(lst, *indices):
    return (lst[i] for i in indices)
```

Usage:

```
>>> def select(lst, *indices):
...     return (lst[i] for i in indices)
...
>>> L = range(0,101,10)
>>> a, b = select(L, 2, 5)
>>> a, b
(20, 50)
```

The way the function works is by returning a [generator object](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) which can be iterated over similarly to any kind of Python sequence.

As @justhalf noted in the comments, your call syntax can be changed by the way you define the function parameters.

```
def select(lst, indices):
    return (lst[i] for i in indices)
```

And then you could call the function with:

```
select(L, [2, 5])
```

or any list of your choice.

**Update:** I now recommend using `operator.itemgetter` instead unless you really need the lazy evaluation feature of generators. See [John Y's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19128597/2653390).

Comment: Do you think defining the function as `select(lst, indices)` and calling it as `select(L, [2,5])` would be better?

Comment: @justhalf Yeah that's possible as well, I'll make a note.

Comment: @Shashank quick question. the "*indices" argument it's just "*args" right? but with a different name?

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez Yes, exactly. :) This is a very old answer however, and I would recommend using `operator.itemgetter` instead unless the lazy-evaluation feature of generators is required.

Answer (score 38):

Probably the closest to what you are looking for is [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) (or look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) for Python 2 docs):

```
>>> L = list(range(0, 101, 10))  # works in Python 2 or 3
>>> L
[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> itemgetter(2, 5)(L)
(20, 50)
```

Comment: @justhalf: Well, `itemgetter` is very similar to Shashank's answer, except already included in the Python standard library.

Comment: It is a nice solution toto, but I think the extra up votes are because it came in slightly sooner... I ultimately chose the one that doesn't require an `import` even though it mainly wrapped the OP in a function definition.

Comment: @beroe: It's still getting more *new* votes even *after* you accepted the other answer, so the earlier time has nothing to do with it. I believe the reason my answer is getting more votes is that experienced Python programmers will usually prefer to use `itemgetter` than to define a new function. One import is shorter and simpler than one function definition.

Comment: Makes sense. I like it as a solution. (I voted for it too ;^)

Comment: For Python 3, the first line would change to `>>> L = list(range(0, 101, 10))` to perform the "identical" operation.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson - true enough, though I was simply preserving what was in the original question. I guess it couldn't hurt to edit my answer anyway.

Answer (score 16):

If you can use `numpy`, you can do just that:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> the_list = numpy.array(range(0,101,10))
>>> the_indices = [2,5,7]
>>> the_subset = the_list[the_indices]
>>> print the_subset, type(the_subset)
[20 50 70] <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> print list(the_subset)
[20, 50, 70]
```

[`numpy.array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) is very similar to `list`, just that it supports more operation, such as mathematical operations and also arbitrary index selection like we see here.

Comment: I think the reason it is not the accepted answer is because (a) it has more bloat, and (b) it is less generalized.  (a): `numpy` is a **huge** library, and this answer pulls the whole thing in.  (Perhaps `from numpy import array`?) (b): `numpy` is *specifically* for mathematical operations, so is less familiar to folks who focus on, for instance, back-end web development.  `itemgetter` is closer to "bare" Python that reaches a wider audience.

Comment: `from numpy import array` will still load the whole numpy package, I believe. But you're right, this might be overkill if the list is not used for math operations.

Answer (score 13):

Just for completeness, the method from the original question is pretty simple. You would want to wrap it in a function if `L` is a function itself, or assign the function result to a variable beforehand, so it doesn't get called repeatedly:

```
[L[x] for x in [2,5]]
```

Of course it would also work for a string...

```
["ABCDEF"[x] for x in [2,0,1]]
['C', 'A', 'B']
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers will work for [multidimensional object](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) slicing. IMHO this is the most general solution (uses `numpy`):

[`numpy.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) allows you to select arbitrary indices in all dimensions of an array simultaneously.

e.g.:

```
>>> a = np.arange(10).reshape(2, 5) # create an array
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
>>> ixgrid = np.ix_([0, 1], [2, 4]) # create the slice-like grid
>>> ixgrid
(array([[0],
       [1]]), array([[2, 4]]))
>>> a[ixgrid]                       # use the grid to slice a
array([[2, 4],
       [7, 9]])
```

Comment: Yes it is too bad python doesn’t have better basic support of array-type data without requiring `numpy`

Answer (score 0):

if you just need to print all the possible combinations of the elements of a list (rather than just consecutive), you can use `combinations` from `itertools`

```
from itertools import combinations
a = [2,4,6,8]
for i in range(len(a)):
    comb = combinations(a, i+1)
    for elem in comb:
        print(elem)
```

This will print:

```
(2,)
(4,)
(6,)
(8,)
(2, 4)
(2, 6)
(2, 8)
(4, 6)
(4, 8)
(6, 8)
(2, 4, 6)
(2, 4, 8)
(2, 6, 8)
(4, 6, 8)
(2, 4, 6, 8)
```

Hope this helps someone.